# How to represent the following pattern in Regex?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, shell

I have a string such as

```
KEY1="VALUE1",KEY2="VALUE2",KEY3="VALUE3" this is the end of line.
```

I am trying to match `KEY1="VALUE1"` type of strings and replace them with newer key values.

Eg: this entire pattern --> `KEY1="VALUE1",` needs to be replaced as `NEW_STUFF`

The regex I am using looks like this:

```
's/"([,]?)$KEY=\".*\"," " "/"$NEW_STUFF"/g`
```

But this is not ending up well. if my `$KEY=KEY1`,

Expectation : `NEW_STUFF KEY2="VALUE2",KEY3="VALUE3" this is the end of line.`

Actual result: `this is the end of line.`

Comment: You say you want to extract the key/value pairs, but your code does a *substitution*. Which do you want?

Comment: @Borodin I want to extract and substitute. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Then you need to explain in more detail what that means, including showing what your file looks like.

Comment: @Borodin really sorry about the confusing question. I have modified my question. Hopefully that is more clear

Comment: So, for example, `$KEY` contains `KEY1` and `$NEW_STUFF` contains `NEW_STUFF`; and you want to do this multiple times with different values for `$KEY` and `$NEW_STUFF`? I presume that in reality `$NEW_STUFF` will be something like `KEY1="NEWSTUFF"`?

Comment: @Borodin No actually, I completely want to replace `KEY1="VALUE1",` by something completely different that is not in the `KEY1=VALUE1` format.Just a phrase like "NEW_STUFF" or "***" etc. I am having trouble at identifying the `,` as the ending point of the search

Comment: Okay take a look at my answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61151/discussion-between-user1357576-and-borodin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my best guess now is that, given a key, you want to replace that key and its value with another arbitrary string. If so then this should be close to what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'KEY1="VALUE1",KEY2="VALUE2",KEY3="VALUE3" etc.';

my $key = 'KEY2';

$str =~ s/ \b $key = " [^"]* " /NEWSTUFF/x;

print $str, "\n";
```

**output**

```
KEY1="VALUE1",NEWSTUFF,KEY3="VALUE3" etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure what it is you want, as your Perl code is strange, and doesn't seem to reflect what you say in the question. However, it is simple enough to process that data format.

I suggest you process the string into a sequence of key/value pairs that you can store in a hash. Then you can simply access whichever value you want.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $str = 'KEY1="VALUE1",KEY2="VALUE2",KEY3="VALUE3" etc.';

my %data = $str =~ / (\w+) = " ([^"]*) " /gx;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{ KEY1 => "VALUE1", KEY2 => "VALUE2", KEY3 => "VALUE3" }
```